# Returning JSON within a C# function - Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-core

I have this piece of code that I want to return an JSON object - I a struggling getting the types correct:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCurrencyAsync()
{
    var Currencies = await _ripple_primary_context.RipplCurrencies.Select(p => new { p.CurrencyId, p.CurrencyName }).ToListAsync();
    var results = JsonSerializer.Serialize(Currencies);

    return results;
}
```

I am getting the error: "cannot convert string to IActionResult". I am trying to just return the JSON. Looking at the blogs it seems I can use Json(results) but I cannot find Json in any using statements.

[image]

Comment: `return Json(result);` or `return Ok(results);` assuming you're using an ASP.NET controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it. You can just create and return type from the endpoint:

```cs
record CurrencyDTO(int CurrencyId, string CurrencyName); // for example using records

public async Task<List<Currency>> GetCurrencyAsync()
{
    var currencies = await _ripple_primary_context
        .RipplCurrencies
        .Select(p => new CurrencyDTO(p.CurrencyId, p.CurrencyName))
        .ToListAsync();

    return currencies;
}
```

Or use `Controller.Json` method:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCurrencyAsync()
{
    var currencies = await _ripple_primary_context
        .RipplCurrencies
        .Select(p => new { p.CurrencyId, p.CurrencyName })
        .ToListAsync();

    return Json(currencies);
}
```

Or use `ControllerBase.Ok` method:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCurrencyAsync()
{
    // ...

    return Ok(currencies);
}
```

Using `IResult` (as far as I remember support in controllers can depend on ASP.NET Core version):

```
public async Task<IResult> GetCurrencyAsync()
{
    // ...

    return Results.Json(currencies);
}
```

Also there is recently introduced option - `TypedResults`.

Read more:

- [Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: yep i was doing it the bottom way but i cannot seem to find the 'Json' command within the using statements.

Comment: @Jason_Hough 1) is this code in controller? Does it inherit from `Controller` or `ControllerBase`? 2) What ASP.NET Core version are you using?

Comment: I am using an Azure function and i have put Entity Framrwork in a Dependncy injection. I am just trying to get all my calls to EF Core in different methods so it looks correct. And i have done your second design and i cannot find Json

Comment: I am using .NET Core 7 as an isolated process function

Comment: @Jason_Hough try `new JsonResult(currencies)`

Comment: public async Task<IActionResult> GetCurrencyAsync()
        {
            var currencies = await _ripple_primary_context
                .RipplCurrencies
                .Select(p => new { p.CurrencyId, p.CurrencyName })
                .ToListAsync();


            JsonResult CurrencyJson = new JsonResult(currencies);

Comment: this is asking for 1 argument ? - I am so lost ,,, but thankyou so far Guru

Comment: @Jason_Hough TBH not following? What is asking for 1 argument? Also no need for interim variable - just return - `return new JsonResult(currencies)`.

Comment: i have added a screenshot into my main question - see what you think to that !!! its crazy I am only returning a json :)

Comment: @Jason_Hough it seems that you are using something from wrong namespace. What is the full type name for `JsonResult`? I have meant the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-7.0). Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38943858/2501279).